# wordpress navigation menu, following text appears on the same line, probably a simple CSS issue

Tags: css, wordpress

At my WordPress-based website http://brilliantzenaudio.com, there is some text that appears to the right of the navigation menu. It's supposed to go on the next line. I tried using the display:block property in a few different places but no luck.

relevant parts of header.php:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
   <div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
      <header id="header" role="banner">
         <img src="<?php get_template_directory()?>/assets/img/brav-banner-3.jpg">
         <nav id="menu" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
         </nav>
      </header>
   <div id="container">
```

front-page.php is

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">
  <div id="info"
       <h4>In the Los Angeles area? </h4> <p>Ask about free demo loaners! </p>
       <h4>We also take mail orders.</h4> On all orders, there is a 30-day return policy!</p> 
  </div>
  <div id="longSlogan">
       <img class="frontpageimg" src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/slogan-2.jpg">

  </div>
  <div id="bunchOfPictures">

       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/cables-ers-absorber-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/blueprint-silencers-v2-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/brav-front-page-700.jpg"/></a>

        <a href="contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-orange">Contact Us</a>
   </div>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

relevant parts of style.css:

```
#header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:90%;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  width:90%;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#longSlogan {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#menu {
  display:block;
  width: 900px;
  background: #222222;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things are causing this:

1. You didnt close a div tag `<div id="info"` needs to be `<div id="info">`
2. Your nav menu has floated elements and without a css style `overflow:hidden` display block is doing nothing.

Make your menu css match this:

```
#navDiv{
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hiding the overflow of the menu can have some negative side effects if you are not using absolute positioning for your drop-downs. So as an alternative you can clear the floats starting with the container div:

```
#container{
    clear: both;
}
```

This will clear both right and left floats from elements above it.

Comment: Adding overflow:hidden does force the main part of the page to start on the next line, but also has a bad side-effect which is preventing the drop-down menus from showing. Any other ideas? In looking at the page with Firebug, I see that the "header" div doesn't seem to include the navigation menu.. which Firebug shows are part of the "container" div.

Comment: Updated my answer to provide an alternate solution.

Comment: Works! I have another question but it's somewhat separate so I'll ask in a new question. In the meantime do you have a reference to a good explanation of what these options (overflow:hidden, clear:both) do? I mean explained from first principles. Because they sound utterly mysterious to me.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ has a pretty good explanation of all the css properties and values.

Answer (score 0):

In your front-page.php you're missing the closing bracket for the div.